# How to concatenate values of a column B grouped by the other column A SQL and R

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(scientific_name = c("Mandevilla grazielae",
                                     "Aosa parvifolia",
                                     "Mandevilla grazielae",
                                     "Dyckia ebracteata"), 
                 collection_number = c("254", "658","445", "568"))
```

And I'd like to combine the collection number of the plants in a column named "vouchers"

```
scientific_name       vouchers
Mandevilla grazielae  254, 445
Aosa parvifolia       658
Dyckia ebracteata     568
```

So far this is what I was able to do:

```
x <- sqldf('SELECT * FROM df GROUP BY scientific_name ORDER BY scientific_name ASC')
```

And then I started to learn more...

```
x <- sqldf('SELECT scientific_name, COUNT(collection_number) 
            FROM df GROUP BY scientific_name ORDER BY scientific_name ASC')
```

I'd like to know if there's something like the COUNT function above to concatenate the column "collection_number" in a "vouchers" column. I also tried CONCAT and it did't work.

I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, use `aggregate` with `paste`

```
aggregate(cbind(vouchers = collection_number) ~ scientific_name, df, toString)
```

-output

```
        scientific_name vouchers
1      Aosa parvifolia      658
2    Dyckia ebracteata      568
3 Mandevilla grazielae 254, 445
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Using the same setup as in the question use `group_concat` to concatenate all collection numbers associated with a scientific name.  1 means the first column in the output or write out the column name in its place, i.e. scientific_name.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select scientific_name, group_concat(collection_number) as vouchers
  from df
  group by 1
  order by 1")
```

giving:

```
       scientific_name vouchers
1      Aosa parvifolia      658
2    Dyckia ebracteata      568
3 Mandevilla grazielae  254,445
```

**2)** Using tidyverse it would be done like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(scientific_name) %>%
  summarize(vendors = toString(collection_number)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(scientific_name)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  scientific_name      vendors 
  <chr>                <chr>   
1 Aosa parvifolia      658     
2 Dyckia ebracteata    568     
3 Mandevilla grazielae 254, 445
```